# Need to do a Loop while a JSON data = a variable

Tags: javascript, json, while-loop

so, i need to get a json data, and got into a little trouble while doing it, not sure on what i did wrong or how could i do it right.

```
[{
"userId": 1,
"title": "A",
"body": "B"
},
{
"userId": 1,
"title": "C",
"body": "D"
},
{
"userId": 2,
"title": "E",
"body": "F"
},

function loadPost (y) {
    $.getJSON(  
    function(data){ 
    var i;
    while (y = data[i].userId) {
    $("#card").append(
        "<p><span class='postTilte'>" + data[i].title +
        "</span>"+ data[i].body + "</p>"
        )
    }}
```

this is something that will be clicked, them the function will roll and what i want to get will loop dependin on the number replacing the variable y on it.

can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to initialize `i=0` and increment the value of `i` in the loop

Answer (score 0):

```
while (y = data[i].userId) {
    $("#card").append(
    "<p><span class='postTilte'>" + data[i].title +
    "</span>"+ data[i].body + "</p>")
    i++;    //increment value of i
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you dont intialize i , it will result in infinite loop and you need increment it properly, refere below code

```
function loadPost (y) {
    $.getJSON(  
    function(data){ 
    var i =0 ;
    while (i<data.length) {
if(y = data[i].userId)
{
    $("#card").append(
        "<p><span class='postTilte'>" + data[i].title +
        "</span>"+ data[i].body + "</p>"
        )
    }
}
i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using *Array* `filter` and `forEach` methods. (Look, Ma, no `i`.)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/nrmft1g8/)

```
var list = [{
    "userId": 1,
    "title": "A",
    "body": "B"
},
{
    "userId": 1,
    "title": "C",
    "body": "D"
},
{
    "userId": 2,
    "title": "E",
    "body": "F"
}]

loadPost(list, 1)

function loadPost(arr, y) {
    var ret = ''
    arr.filter(function (val, idx, aa) {
        return val.userId === y
    }).forEach(function (elem) {
        ret += '<p><span class="postTilte">' + elem.title +
            '</span>' + elem.body + '</p>'
    })
    $("#card").append(ret);
}
```